# Ошибка в регулярном выражении на Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Мне надо вычленить все предложения из текста (кроме первого предложения), где есть фраза про километры.

```
Магазин Автозапчастей находится в городе Москва. До него ехать 12 км. В магазине продаются автозапчасти от автомобиля Нива. Курган находится в 1000 км от магазина.
```

Предложения я вычленяю от точки до точки. Но маска не работает. Подскажите в чем ошибка.

```
import re

print('введите текст:')
x1 = str(input())
pattern = re.findall('\.\s\w+\s+(\d км*).*?\.', x1)
print(pattern)
```

Comment: Аббревиатур не предвидится?

Comment: названия в кавычках могут быть. Т.е. может быть с ними, а может быть и без них

Comment: Если точки могут быть внутри предложения, тогда надо их учитывать. Иначе, подошло бы `re.findall(r'[^.]*\d\s*(?:километр|км)[^.]*\.', x1)` ([демо](https://ideone.com/ePDKEB)).

Comment: внутри предложения не будет точек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = 'Магазин Автозапчастей находится в городе Москва. До него ехать 12 км. В магазине продаются автозапчасти от автомобиля Нива. Курган находится в 1000 км от магазина. '

items = re.findall('[^.]*\d+\s+км.*?\.', text)
print(items)  # ['До него ехать 12 км.', 'Курган находится в 1000 км от магазина.']
```

---

Или попробуйте сделать сначала разбитие на предложения (считаем что они отделяются точками с пробелом), а после анализируем каждую часть ища в ней упоминание километров.

В отличии от варианта выше этот вариант более устойчивый:

```
import re

text = 'Магазин Автозапчастей находится в городе Москва. До него ехать 12 км. Магазин Автозапчастей находится в городе Москва. В магазине продаются автозапчасти от автомобиля Нива. Курган находится в 1000 км от магазина.'

items = list(filter(lambda text: re.search('\d+\s+км', text), text.split('. ')))
print(items)  # ['До него ехать 12 км', 'Курган находится в 1000 км от магазина.']
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает

Comment: @Каролина [Не думаю, что `'\. (.+?\d+\s+км.*?\.)'` сработает](https://regex101.com/r/aPcBCC/1) в других случаях, когда предложение в начале текста или после предложения без упоминания километров.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а как вам вариант split + filter?

Comment: Лучше. Кстати, "ча", "ща" пиши с буквой ... :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ага :) Кст, оформите, пожалуйста ваш вариант с `re.findall(r'[^.]*\d\s*(?:километр|км)[^.]*\.', x1)` да хотя бы с `[^.]*\d\s* км[^.]*\.` -- работает ведь, я проверял :)

Comment: хороший вариант